# Passing dates to stored procedure as parameter where null value does not pass any dates or nulls

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, datetimepicker, optional-parameters

I have found many stack overflow articles that refers to this problem but nothing has seem to work for me yet.

Using a Windows Forms application VS 2015. SQL Server 2012 stored procedure accepts many parameters or null values and works fine in SQL Server.

I have two date time pickers getting dates in between both dates

This is my code:

```
using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbstring()))
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("HelpDesk_GetManagementReportInformation_v3", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TicketNo", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTicketNo.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtTicketNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group_Assignment", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGroupName.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtGroupName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStatus.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtStatus.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Urgency", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUrgency.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtUrgency.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket_Category", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTicketCategory.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtTicketCategory.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Requestor", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRequestor.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtRequestor.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Closure_Reason", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClosureReason.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)txtClosureReason.Text);

    SqlParameter BeginDateTimeParam = new SqlParameter("@BeginCreateDate", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBeginDate.Text).ToShortDateString()) ? DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBeginDate.Text).ToShortDateString());
    BeginDateTimeParam.IsNullable = true;
    BeginDateTimeParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    BeginDateTimeParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
    BeginDateTimeParam.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBeginDate.Text).ToShortDateString()) ? DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBeginDate.Text).ToShortDateString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(BeginDateTimeParam);

    SqlParameter EndDateTimeParam = new SqlParameter("@EndCreateDate", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBeginDate.Text).ToShortDateString()) ? DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBeginDate.Text).ToShortDateString());
    BeginDateTimeParam.IsNullable = true;
    BeginDateTimeParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    BeginDateTimeParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
    EndDateTimeParam.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEndDate.Text).ToShortDateString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add(EndDateTimeParam);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgvDataResult.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Version two of the stored procedure has everything except the date parameters.

I had also attempted many other variations of the above code nothing seems to work

Comment: FYI you set the properties on `BeginDateTimeParam` twice instead of setting them on `EndDateTimeParam`.  Also, you need to define what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: What I mean that it does not work. There appears to be no error when I run the applcation but, it does not return the correct data. I believe that it has something to do with passing a null value. I can search via any fields and it does not return any results. I fixed the errors you mentioned. I was doing a lot of copy and pasting

Comment: I corrected the properties SQLParameter EndDateTimeParam. I do not know how to edit my question to make the correction also the date picker was also corrected